# Removing last n characters from Unix Filename before the extension

Tags: file-rename

I have a bunch of files in Unix Directory :

```
  test_XXXXX.txt  
  best_YYY.txt   
  nest_ZZZZZZZZZ.txt
```

I need to rename these files as

```
  test.txt   
  best.txt   
  nest.txt
```

I am using Ksh on AIX  .Please let me know how i can accomplish the above using a Single command .

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one time (or not very often) occasion, I would create a script with

```
$ ls > rename.sh
$ vi rename.sh
:%s/\(.*\)/mv \1 \1/
(edit manually to remove all the XXXXX from the second file names)
:x
$ source rename.sh
```

If this need occurs frequently, I would need more insight into what XXXXX, YYY, and ZZZZZZZZZZZ are.

---

Addendum

Modify this to your liking:

```
ls | sed "{s/\(.*\)\(............\)\.txt$/mv \1\2.txt \1.txt/}" | sh
```

It transforms filenames by omitting 12 characters before `.txt` and passing the resulting `mv` command to a shell.

Beware:  If there are non-matching filenames, it executes the filename—and not a `mv` command.  I omitted a way to select only matching filenames.

Comment: Let me then say this :   Remove the last 12 characters before the .txt in the Filenames.

Comment: I was probably thinking how this could be done for the Last n characters before the Extension .txt , where n is variable. But to be specific it is the last 12 characters.Also this has to done often.

Comment: @user2417881:  I have amended my answer.  Note that it is limited in scope.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it seems you have an `_` to start every section you want to remove. If that's the case, then this ought to work:

```
for f in *.txt
do
  g="${f%%_*}.txt"
  echo mv "${f}" "${g}"
done
```

Remove the `echo` if the output seems correct, or replace the last line with `done | ksh`.

If the files aren't all `.txt` files, this is a little more general:

```
for f in *
do
  ext="${f##*.}"
  g="${f%%_*}.${ext}"
  echo mv "${f}" "${g}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do i extend your code to a situation where i have to remove the last 12 chracters before the extension .txt for eg .

Comment: If it's exactly 12, `${f%????????????}` (12 `?`s) will work after you've already stripped off the extension, if your `ksh` is new enough... Or maybe `${f%{12}(?)}`. These are all newer features in some versions of `ksh` though, so check `man ksh` on your system for more info...