# How can I remove the last n characters of filenames in a certain directory (in Mac terminal)- unix?

Tags: macos, unix, rename

I am trying to rename using "mv", because "rename" command doesn't work in my Mac terminal.

I have a bunch of files named

```
DTM001_ACGGT-TTAGGC.fq
DTM156_GGTTG-ACAGTG.fq
```

...etc

I wish to rename them to

```
DTM001.fq
DTM156.fq
```

I suppose the easier way is to remove the last 13 characters before the file extension?

I tried these links:

- [mac os x terminal batch rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102974/mac-os-x-terminal-batch-rename)
- [Rename file by removing last n characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530429/rename-file-by-removing-last-n-characters)
- [Removing last n characters from Unix Filename before the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601353/removing-last-n-characters-from-unix-filename-before-the-extension)

but none have worked for me, perhaps because I do not fully understand how to manipulate the answers for my specific case or some answers use "rename" command which I cannot access.

Answer (score 5):

The macOS Terminal is simply an interface to an interactive program called a shell. The default shell's name is `bash`.

What you are looking for is known as a shell script, or a bash script, to rename files.

The questions you referenced have the answer. To reiterate:

```sh
cd directory_with_the_files
for file in *.fq; do
    mv -vn "${file}" "${file%_*}.fq"
done
```

You can type this all in at the command line, or place it into a file and execute it with:

```sh
bash file_containing_the_commands
```

This will go through all `.fq` files in the current directory, renaming them to what you want. The `-v` option to `mv` simply means to print the rename as it happens (useful to know that it's doing something), and the `-n` flag means don't accidentally overwrite any files (in case you type something in wrong or come across duplicate numbers).

All the magic is happening in the `${file%_*}.fq`, which says
"remove everything after the first `_` and add the `.fq` back". This is known as a "shell parameter expansion," which you can read more about in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). It's somewhat obtusely worded, but here is the relevant bit to this particular use case:

> ${*parameter*%*word*}
>
> The *word* is expanded to produce a
>   pattern just as in filename expansion. If the pattern matches a
>   trailing portion of the expanded value of *parameter*, then the result
>   of the expansion is the value of *parameter* with the shortest matching
>   pattern (the '%' case) deleted.

Comment: This is great, but, could you provide a specific example with my filenames? I get this message: `$file': not a valid identifier

Comment: I tried changing $file for $DTM. I also tried changing $file for $DTM???

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. It should be `file`, not `$file` in the `for` construct. I've updated the answer.

Comment: It's really just an arbitrary name; you change it to `puppy` if you really wanted to. We call it `file` just because it helps make the program more understandable. When the `for` loop is going through the files in the directory, it tells the program to fill in a variable named `file` with the one it's working on. You pull the contents out of this variable using the `$name` or `${name}` syntax. It's a little confusing, but the mistake was that we tried to set the name of this variable to "whatever is in the variable `file`," which is not what we were intending to do.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to use `rename` - see instructions at the end for installation on a Mac.

So, in answer to your question, you can see what would happen if you replace (the command is actually `s` for *"substitute"*) everything from the first underscore to the end of the filename with `.fq`:

```
rename --dry-run  's/_.*/.fq/'   *fq

'DTM001_ACGGT-TTAGGC.fq' would be renamed to 'DTM001.fq'
'DTM156_GGTTG-ACAGTG.fq' would be renamed to 'DTM156.fq'
```

If that looks good, remove the `--dry-run` and run it again for real.

---

You can use `rename` on your Mac, if you install it. By default, Apple doesn't ship a package manager with `macOS`. So, many folk use `homebrew` from [the homebrew website](http://brew.sh).

If you have that, you can simply install `rename` with:

```
brew install rename
```

Then, you'll have a package manager and you can benefit for all sorts of lovely software including new, up-to-date versions of all the out-of-date, ancient versions of your favourite tools that Apple ships:

- PHP
- Perl
- ImageMagick
- GNU sed
- GNU awk
- GNU find
- GNU Parallel
- zeromq
- htop
- socat
- sox
- ffmpeg
- youtube-dl
- zenity
- redis
- feh
- mosquitto
- doxygen
- pandoc etc.