# How to rename these files in bulk via shell and regular expressions?

Tags: regex, macos, shell

I trying to modify a lot of files with names like `2020-06-28 16.19.50.md`, removing the spaces and symbols, retain only the first 12 digits as `202006281619.md`.

Hopefully this can be done with a shell script through Regular Expressions. Selecting these files in the macOS Finder, right-click and run the Service script to complete the changes.

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/50606088/2836621

Comment: Try something like this to remove spaces, dots and dashes `s/[ .-]//g`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you, and then how do I remove the last two digits (remove 5 and 0  in this example, there's no underscore here)?

Comment: Try `substr($_,0,12)`

Comment: Consider also using `-X` to preserve the extension.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Regular Expressions.
But this can remove spaces of current directory's file names.

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" "$(echo $f | sed 's/ //'g)" ; done
```